# How to fix Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #3, at Function.Sizzle.error (jquery-3.6.0.js:1681)

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, sizzle

[image]

I am using jQuery version 3.6.0 but while toggling between the radio buttons got the error in the console as shown in the screenshot.

Any suggestion on the fix will be appreciated.

Comment: Please add the HTML and JS which causes this error to the question.